# Integration Google Analytics in Swift App

Tags: xcode, swift, google-analytics

I follow this manual(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift#get-config) to integrate Google analytics in my app. But i getting some error when i try to test it!

> ```
> ld: framework not found GoogleInterchangeUtilities
> ```

I have already made this:

1)in podfile:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics' -> pod install
```

2) in APP-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "Google/Analytics.h"
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceFields.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProduct.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProductAction.h"
#import "GAIEcommercePromotion.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAILogger.h"
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
```

3) GoogleService-Info.plist already added to my project. But i don't understand what google mean say: "Add GoogleService-Info.plist to each target!!!"

I try add a GoogleInterchangeUtilities framework to "Link Binary With Libraries" and "Copy Frameworks" but it did not help!

[image]

Help me please!

Comment: Do you really need to add all of the files in the bridge-header, does it work if you only add `#import "Google/Analytics.h` ?

Comment: I have tried to add only Google/Analytics.h... The error in this case is the same!

Comment: When you drag the `GoogleService-Info.plist ` inside your project did you add it to every target ? In this [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_File_or_Folder.html) you would have to add it to `MyApp` and `MyAppTest`, try remove it then add it again and make sure you did add it to every of your target. Also don't forget to copy the item into destination (first option to check)

Comment: xcode don't show me this window! i can not select targets... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem a couple of days ago.  You should follow these steps.

- Install Cocoapods
- In Terminal, navigate to the directory which has your Xcode Project in it.
- Type `pod init`
- Then type `pod install` (I know this sounds early but I will explain)
- Open the workspace file and find the podfile that was created by Cocoapods.  Edit that file to include `pod 'Google/Analytics'`
- Go back to terminal and type `pod install` again.  I could get not get Cocoapods to work with the podfile I created, so had to use the one they created.
- Now, upon install, you should see that items have been downloaded.
- Go back into the workspace file, and set up your `-Bridging-Header.h`
- Type this into the `-Bridging-Header.h`  `#import "Google/Analytics.h"`
- If for some reason that doesn't work (it didn't for me), the type each individual item.
- Be sure to add the correct directory for your -Bridging-Header.h. You can find this under Project - Build Settings - Swift Compiler Code Generation. Use this to easily target your header file $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h
- Drag the `.plist` file into Xcode and select all of the targets, as seen in the below picture.
  [image]

You will know that everything has installed correctly when you look into the Navigator in Xcode and see a PODS folder with a bunch of Google stuff in it.  It should look like this in the navigator.
[image]

That should have you squared away.  I ran into many issues very similar to yours.  Let me know if you need clarification on something.

Comment: xcode dont show me this window (http://i.stack.imgur.com/eTNnG.png) when i add .plist! I don't understand why!

Comment: How are you adding it?  To get that window, I drag the file in from Finder, directly into the Xcode Navigator.

Comment: I have already add .plist to each target! Xcode showed me a window on the fifth attempt!

Comment: but the error remained! ld: framework not found GoogleInterchangeUtilities
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @Dmitry Wow, that's strange.  I'm glad it worked for you to get that far!  Let me know how the rest works out.

Comment: @Dmitry did you reinstall the pod via Cocoapods in the Terminal?  Can you confirm that the pod files are located in your project?  I will update the answer to show what you should look for.

Comment: I really need to reinstall  Cocoapods?? I don't understand why!! But if you insisting - I'll do it! i have already updated my question!

Comment: Try to reinstall the pod into the project, not Cocoapods.  Follow the steps in my answer and let me know how it works.

Comment: I follow your step, and XCode missed some libraries like Facebook and VK... now i have 8 errors! ld: framework not found GoogleInterchangeUtilities also present! =((

Comment: Not at my computer right now. Will look into in a bit. But... Did you include the other pods to install in the podfile?

Comment: Then it should have installed those as well. Did you change the bridging header location or adjust any of those settings?

Comment: Yes, i change the bridging header location! But FBSDK don't set in it!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. FBSDK is not working when importing into the bridging header?

Comment: Thank you for your help! It was a mistake in the CocoaPods 1.0! Now everything works fine!