# Upgrade to Swift 3 Error- ld: framework not found GoogleInterchangeUtilities

Tags: ios, sdk, swift3, crash, frameworks

I just upgraded to `Swift 3` from `2.2`. I'm using `Firebase`, `Google Maps`, `Google Places`, `SwiftyJSON`, `Alamofire 4.4`, and `SDWebImage`. I reinstalled all the `pods`, ran `git commit`, and fixed all the errors except this one:

> ld: framework not found GoogleInterchangeUtilities clang:
>
> error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> (null): Framework not found
>   GoogleInterchangeUtilities
>
> (null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

**Where do I find `GoogleInterchangeUtilities` and how do I install or fix it?**

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306621/integration-google-analytics-in-swift-app) helps solve your problem.

Comment: @ f_qi thanks I'm looking it over

Comment: @ f_qi I resolved the issue, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I upgraded from `Swift 2.2` to `Swift 3` the first thing I did was clean and remove my `cocoapods`:

```
pod deintegrate
pod clean
pod cache clean --all
rm Podfile
```

For some reason when I reinstalled all of the pods I originally had, the `GoogleInterchangeUtilities` file plus several others were removed in the process:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Removing GoogleInterchangeUtilities //**REMOVED**
Removing GoogleNetworkingUtilities //**REMOVED**
Removing GoogleParsingUtilities //**REMOVED**
Removing GoogleSymbolUtilities //**REMOVED**
Removing GoogleUtilities //**REMOVED**
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire 3.5.1 (was 3.4.1)
Installing Firebase 3.15.0 (was 3.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 3.7.0 (was 3.2.1)
Installing FirebaseAuth 3.1.1 (was 3.0.3)
Installing FirebaseCore (3.5.2)
Installing FirebaseCrash 1.1.6 (was 1.0.6)
Installing FirebaseDatabase 3.1.2 (was 3.0.2)
Installing FirebaseDynamicLinks 1.3.4 (was 1.1.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID 1.0.9 (was 1.0.7)
Installing FirebaseStorage 1.1.0 (was 1.0.2)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.9)
Installing GoogleMaps 2.2.0 (was 1.13.2)
Using GooglePlacesAPI (1.0.6)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Installing ObjectMapper 1.5.0 (was 1.3.0)
Installing Protobuf (3.2.0)
Using SDWebImage (3.8.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 10 dependencies from the Podfile and 17 total pods installed.
```

I eventually went to Google and typed in `GoogleInterchangeUtilities` which led me to it's pod install page [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities). I reinstalled the pod which removed the error but then each of the other files that were removed resulted in their own `ld: framework not found...` Xcode errors.

Long story short if you cleaned and removed your cocoapods file and reinstalled everything, there's a possibility the `Google...Utilities` frameworks will get removed. You have to include those specific individual pods back in your pod file and run: `pod install` again.

Here is my pod file with them included in addition to all  my other pods:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myProject

pod 'GoogleInterchangeUtilities', '~> 1.2'
pod 'GoogleNetworkingUtilities', '~> 1.2'
pod 'GoogleParsingUtilities', '~> 1.1'
pod 'GoogleSymbolUtilities', '~> 1.1'
pod 'GoogleUtilities', '~> 1.3'

//all my other pods...
```

Here are their cocoapods install pages:

[GoogleInterchangeUtilities](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities)

[GoogleNetworkingUtilities](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities)

[GoogleParsingUtilities](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleParsingUtilities)

[GoogleSymbolUtilities](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities)

[GoogleUtilities](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleUtilities)

Comment: You Sir, are a saviour.